# How can I set date to topresent option in Javascript or php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Please help me in setting a date option to to-present in either php,javascript, jquery or ajax

Comment: In order to get help on this website, you have to show a minimum willingness to solve your own problem. The format is Q & A, not "write my code".

Comment: And for your own future reference, jQuery is a framework written in Javascript, and AJAX is a technique for making asynchronous HTTP requests using Javascript. They are not different languages, as your question implies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use date('Y-m-d') in php and new Date() in js..